# Filter specific dates between columns that contain years

Tags: sql-server

is there an easy way to filter a specific date between two columns that contain dates?  I want to show all employees that were hired within a specific beginning and ending year.  In the employee calendar there are several years, with a column showing the CalendarYear as (ex. 2001-2002, 2005-2006, etc.). If the employees were hired between 02/01/2001 and 01/02/2002, i want to show the CalendarYear to show as 2001-2002, in a column.

```
select hr.EmployeeID
hr.EmploymentHireDate
,emp.CalendarBeginYear
,emp.CalendarEndYear
,emp.CalendarYear
,case when EmployeeHireDate between CalendarBeginYear and CalendarEndYear then CalendarYear else null
end as CalendarEnbdYear
     from HR_Employee hr
    join EmployeeCalendar em
    hr.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
```

I know I'm missing something, or doing something wrong.
Thank you for any assistance,

Comment: Is there really an `EmployeeId` on `EmployeeCalendar` ?

Comment: First things first...is that February 1st, 2001 through January 2nd, 2002? It is impossible to tell which date is which based on your example. Next question would be how do you know what the cutoffs are for each year, presumably they are not the same every year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
   hr.EmployeeID
 , hr.EmploymentHireDate
 , emp.CalendarYear
from HR_Employee hr
  inner join EmployeeCalendar em 
    on hr.EmployeeHireDate >= emp.CalendarBeginYear
   and hr.EmployeeHireDate <= emp.CalendarEndYear
   and hr.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID -- < there is a calendar for each employee?
```

I do not know why `EmployeeId` would be on the calendar, but if it isn't, remove the last line of the join and it should return what you are looking for. If it `EmployeeId` is on the calendar table, then the query above should work as intended.